# FreeNAS working - WebGUI non existant - services refuse to start

Tags: nginx, freebsd, django, freenas

I've had a FreeNAS box (at home) running for a few months now, everything's been fine but it doesn't have a UPS and recently after it was hard shutdown there have been issues.

I can't access the WebGUI at all, Samba/WebDAV are both off, AFP is on, but doesn't work due to the drives being encrypted and SSH works.

I can login through SSH fine, but attempting to restart nginx or django (as recommended when the WebGUI doesn't work) does nothing.

```
[root@x] /# service nginx restart
Performing sanity check on nginx configuration:
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "upload_progress" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

[root@x] /# service django restart
django not running? (check /var/run/django.pid).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/www/freenasUI/manage.py", line 40, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I have no idea, I've used Linux for hosting sites with Apache2 but never used nginx or django and no idea what these errors mean. Googling them doesn't give any suggestions, relevant to FreeNAS or otherwise

Oh, although it's a pain, I wouldn't mind reinstalling FreeNAS but I have no idea how to backup the configuration using command line. I've just copied the SQLite files from /data

Thanks

Comment: My experience is that *nix and *BSD OSs don't like power being removed. Even just a cheap UPS can save a huge amount of headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like your system drive (USB?) might be failing or an update went wrong. The configuration should be here:

```
/data/FreeNAS-v1.db
```

Reinstalling is probably the easiest way out of this. If you start to manually repair it, there is no guarantee an update won't crash it again.

Comment: Thanks. To anyone else having this issue in the future I imaged the USB drive (as I didn't know what I needed from it) and reinstalled FreeNAS to the USB drive. Copying the config off the image and uploading it to a clean FreeNAS worked initially, but in the end I reinstalled clean (again) and just imported a foreign volume. (NOTE: if you use encryption on the drives, make sure you have the 'geli' recovery files up to date!!). Thanks to mzhaase

Answer (score 0):

218/5000
Hi, I solved by creating a reservation on my router with physical address mac and assigning the exact address. at this point, restarting Freenas, the exact address is back, and now everything works as before.